# Using parent data as the zerotext of a nested repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, kentico, nested-repeater

If my nested repeater returns no results, I want the zerotext result to be from the parent item. I can't figure it out; I've read around the issue but nothing seems to cover this specifically. I'm using Kentico EMS v6.

Is it even possible? Thanks, Oli.

Comment: Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts, or they will be removed.http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Are you using the Portal or ASPX model?

Comment: @Doozer, Portal model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible unless you modify the code of the web part. Reason: you can use only plain text or macro in the 'No record found text' field and macro can not be evaluated to such thing as parent's 'No record found text'.